# Rust - evaluate result in Option map closure

Tags: rust

I am trying to map value inside Option and if it is missing then I want to return Error.  Currently I am using approach:

```
pub fn unmarshall_root(opt: Option<String>) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let res = match opt {
        Some(s) => unmarshall_child(s)?,
        None => return Err(new_error(String::from("input must be defined"))),
    };

    Ok(res)
}

pub fn unmarshall_child(o: String) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    Ok(o)
}
```

It works fine, but want something more elegant. Something like:

```
opt.map(|it| unmarshall_child(it)?)
    .ok_or_else(Err(new_error(String::from("input must be defined"))))
```

Which cannot be compiled (err message: "cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns"). Any recommendation for more elegant approach?

EDIDTED: Thanks for all proposed approaches. I have another question, how to handle situation more elegantly when I do not to fail if value is empty:

```
pub fn unmarshall_root(opt: Option<String>) -> Result<Option<String>, io::Error> {
    let res = match opt {
        Some(s) => Some(unmarshall_child(s)?),
        None => None,
    };

    Ok(res)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is more elegant, but you can rewrite it like:

```rust
unmarshall_child(
    opt.ok_or_else(|| new_error(String::from("input must be defined")))?,
)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the unnecessary unwrapping-and-rewrapping, you'd have:

```
pub fn unmarshall_root(opt: Option<String>) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    match opt {
        Some(s) => unmarshall_child(s),
        None => Err(new_error(String::from("input must be defined"))),
    }
}
```

This is already pretty straightforward. A common rearrangement (if you need to operate on `s` a bit more than once) is:

```
pub fn unmarshall_root(opt: Option<String>) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let s = if let Some(s) = opt {
        s
    } else {
        return Err(new_error(String::from("input must be defined")));
    };

    // ...

    unmarshall_child(s)
}
```

This gives good flexibility without over-closurifying the code.

---

When [`let-else`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html) is finalized, this can be written:

```
pub fn unmarshall_root(opt: Option<String>) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let Some(s) = opt else {
        return Err(new_error(String::from("input must be defined")));
    };

    unmarshall_child(s)
}
```

---

But if you really must one-line it, then:

```
pub fn unmarshall_root(opt: Option<String>) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    opt.ok_or_else(|| new_error(String::from("input must be defined")))
        .and_then(unmarshall_child)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, can you also recommend me some approaches when I do not want to fail if value is empty (I added exaple code in original question). Thanks you.

Comment: @billyvoiderer It would be good to take some of the forms given in the answers to your questions and play around with them to see. It's also helpful to explore the rustdocs on `Option` and `Result` to see if you can "fit the puzzle pieces" together on how to get between them. In your additional example, probably something like `opt.map(unmarshall_child).transpose()`.

Comment: Generally, `and_then()` is equivalent to the `?` operator. As for the unwrapping and rewrapping, it may be necessary in longer functions.

Comment: @GManNickG thanks a lot, transpose() is what I wanted.